# Tables in latex - problems with text after a table

Tags: tables

I have problems with tables in latex. I want to have text before a table and I cannot do that. I don't know why the text wrote by me is written after the table. Any help?

[image]

Here is the code for making table which I used in my project:

```
\begin{table}
\small
\begin{tabular}{p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}p{3.5cm}}
\hline
I(mA) &1mA &5mA &7mA\\
\hline
R(k$\ohm$)  &0.415k$\ohm$ &0.415k$\ohm$ &0.415k$\ohm$\\
\hline
U(V)   &0.175V &0.077V &0.107V
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I hope you don't use the image as a background of the table... now the real 'problem' is that your table 'floats' away. If you don't need a caption (there is none there), you can omit the `\begin{table}...\end{table}` pair. Replace them with `{...}` only (such that the `\small` font declaration does not leak into the rest of the document.

Comment: Try `\begin{table}[htb]`

Comment: Lots of people are confused by this behaviour. What happens is that the `table` (and `figure`) environment are *floating* environments, which means that LaTeX can move them around to avoid bad page breaks. For example if you have a big table that doesn't fit in what's left of the page, then LaTeX can move text from after the table before it, so you don't get a half-empty page. Then instead of saying "the following table", you add a `\caption` and `\label`, and use `\ref` to add a cross-reference to the table. This isn't always what you want though, and then you can do something like (ctd.)

Comment: what @ChristianHupfer did in his answer, and remove the `table` environment altogether. It is not required to surround a `tabular` with this environment. Similarly, one doesn't need a `figure` environment around an `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 2):

Here a two strategies (and a third one, with floating table as the O.P. has already, which does not produce the requested result)

1. Omit the `\begin{table}...\end{table}` pair and use `{\small\centering ...}`  instead to prevent font declaration leaking into the rest of the document. The table will be centered then. For a caption you need `\captionof{table}{Your caption text}`.
2. Try `\begin{table}[htb]`

In both cases the table stays at the desired position, keeping the text above as desired.

In addition, I've changed the look and dimensions of the table a little bit, using `siunitx` and `tabularx` packages.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{table}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{X}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{The floating table} \tabularnewline
\hline
I(\si{\mA}) &1 &5 &7\tabularnewline
\hline
R(\si{\kohm})  &0.415 &0.415 &0.415\tabularnewline
\hline
U(\si{V})   &0.175 &0.077 &0.107
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\clearpage

\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{X}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{The non - floating table with \texttt{[htb]}} \tabularnewline
\hline
I(\si{\mA}) &1 &5 &7\tabularnewline
\hline
R(\si{\kohm})  &0.415 &0.415 &0.415\tabularnewline
\hline
U(\si{V})   &0.175 &0.077 &0.107
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\clearpage


\blindtext

{%
\centering
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{X}}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{The non-floating floating table} \tabularnewline
\hline
I(\si{\mA}) &1 &5 &7\tabularnewline
\hline
R(\si{\kohm})  &0.415 &0.415 &0.415\tabularnewline
\hline
U(\si{V})   &0.175 &0.077 &0.107
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{My still improvable table}
}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```